# How we make the search efficent in combobox if it is editable?

Tags: wpf, combobox

```
<ComboBox Name="cbDesignation" IsEditable="True" TextSearch.TextPath="DesignationName" 
    StaysOpenOnEdit="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DesignationCollection,Mode=TwoWay}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDesignation,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DesignationName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

If it is editable then it search but only one item I want that whrn user enter start of alphabet then it will show all the list regardin this alphabet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about an AutoComplete TextBox instead? It also uses suggestions and does all the filtering for you. You can find one here:
http://wpfactb.codeplex.com/
(more info here: http://blogs.windowsclient.net/dragonz/archive/2010/02/23/autocomplete-textbox-control-for-wpf.aspx)